# Web application redirects when accessing CSS file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7.5

I've created web site in c:\website folder using visual studio 2010. Then, I've created web site in IIS 7.5 that maps to that folder. However when I access Default.aspx page and request to css is issued like

http://localhost/webapp/Styles/Site.css

it's redirected to something like this:

http://localhost/website/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fwebsite%2fStyles%2fSite.css

Any ideas what is going on?

Thanks , Paweł

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you have restricted security settings in your web.config? Check out the 
 attribute in this file.

If it looks anything like this:

```
<authorization>
<deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Then this is likely the issue. Alternatively if you are using Windows authentication then review the user account settings within IIS.

Comment: That's right. I have to work on my security background knowledge. Thanks